# SharePoint provider hosted app 403 error using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

I am creating a provider hosted app for SharePoint online and trying to get a list using rest API in a view but I am getting

> 403 error access denied error.

I have already set permissions in app Manifest file (Web- Full control). Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cross domain library for this.
Sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cross-domain sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- This is the placeholder for the announcements -->
    <div id="renderAnnouncements"></div>
    <script 
        type="text/javascript" 
        src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var hostweburl;
      var appweburl;

      // Load the required SharePoint libraries
      $(document).ready(function () {
        //Get the URI decoded URLs.
        hostweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(
                getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
        );
        appweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(
                getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
        );

        // resources are in URLs in the form:
        // web_url/_layouts/15/resource
        var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

        // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
      });

      // Function to prepare and issue the request to get
      //  SharePoint data
      function execCrossDomainRequest() {
        // executor: The RequestExecutor object
        // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the add-in web URL.
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

        // Issue the call against the add-in web.
        // To get the title using REST we can hit the endpoint:
        //      appweburl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
        // The response formats the data in the JSON format.
        // The functions successHandler and errorHandler attend the
        //      sucess and error events respectively.
        executor.executeAsync(
            {
              url:
                  appweburl +
                  "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Announcements')/items",
              method: "GET",
              headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
              success: successHandler,
              error: errorHandler
            }
        );
      }

      // Function to handle the success event.
      // Prints the data to the page.
      function successHandler(data) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        var announcementsHTML = "";

        var results = jsonObject.d.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          announcementsHTML = announcementsHTML +
              "<p><h1>" + results[i].Title +
              "</h1>" + results[i].Body +
              "</p><hr>";
        }

        document.getElementById("renderAnnouncements").innerHTML =
            announcementsHTML;
      }

      // Function to handle the error event.
      // Prints the error message to the page.
      function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        document.getElementById("renderAnnouncements").innerText =
            "Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorMessage;
      }

      // Function to retrieve a query string value.
      // For production purposes you may want to use
      //  a library to handle the query string.
      function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
        var params =
            document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&amp;");
        var strParams = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
          var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
          if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
        }
      }
    </script>
</body>
```

Some links for your reference.
https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/access-sharepoint-data-from-add-ins-using-the-cross-domain-library

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uksharepoint/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api/